# Why is my site down and giving "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found," even though I haven't made any changes lately?

Tags: mysql, pdo

My website which has been using PDO for over a year now is suddenly down and giving this error today:

```
>     Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/?????/public_html/includes/connection.php:16 Stack trace: #0
> /home/?????/public_html/index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown
> in /home/????/public_html/includes/connection.php on line 16
```

I haven't made ANY changes to the site or MySQL database in months, so it doesn't really make sense that it would just break out of nowhere.  Any ideas/suggestions on what I should check?  I changed all my MySQL queries to use PDO a year ago to be more secure but don't know much about it other than that.

```
<?php 
//PDO connection
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'XXXXX';
$user = 'XXXXX';
$pass = 'XXXXX';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
?>
```

Comment: Contact your provider? This sounds like something nobody here could possibly help with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a 'Class PDO not found' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617937/getting-a-class-pdo-not-found-error)